# How to convert attachment file to different format in odoo?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12, odoo-13

How to add an observer on attachment upload in odoo to check for a certain file type and to do operation on this file? For example to convert to another format on upload.

EDIT

`values` variable that is modified in my code still has no effect in `addons/web/controllers/main.py:upload_attachment()`, as there file storage variable is an old, unmodified still.

EDIT2

Here I have added the error from when I try to change the name of the file uploaded in the custom function. Because in the method `addons/web/controllers/main.py:upload_attachment()` old upload file name persists.

```
ERROR odoo13 odoo.addons.web.controllers.main: Fail to upload attachment docum2.doc 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/computer/13-ver-odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1512, in upload_attachment
    attachment = Model.create({
  File "<decorator-gen-94>", line 2, in create
  File "/home/computer/13-ver-odoo/odoo/api.py", line 314, in _model_create_single
    return create(self, arg)
  File "/home/computer/13-ver-odoo/local-addons/crm_checklist/models/ir_attachment.py", line 54, in create
    return super(IrAttachment, self).create(values)
  File "<decorator-gen-39>", line 2, in create
  File "/home/computer/13-ver-odoo/odoo/api.py", line 335, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, [arg])
  File "/home/computer/13-ver-odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_attachment.py", line 515, in create
    values.update(self._get_datas_related_values(values.pop('datas'), values['mimetype']))
  File "/home/computer/13-ver-odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_attachment.py", line 212, in _get_datas_related_values
    bin_data = base64.b64decode(data) if data else b''
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/base64.py", line 80, in b64decode
    s = _bytes_from_decode_data(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/base64.py", line 45, in _bytes_from_decode_data
    raise TypeError("argument should be a bytes-like object or ASCII "
TypeError: argument should be a bytes-like object or ASCII string, not 'tuple'
```

Comment: To check the file on upload, you can extend the binary widget and ovveride the [on_file_uploaded_and_valid(size, name, content_type, file_base64)](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/web/static/src/js/fields/basic_fields.js#L1483) method

Comment: Thank you @Kenly for the reply, but I need to check it on the backend, in python code, to convert the file right away.

Comment: You can convert the file before it is written to the database, check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file upload is handled by the web client and it is written in javascript.

To convert the file in the backend (Python), you need to convert the file before it is written to the database and to do that you need to override the `create/write` methods.

***Example: using the `ir.attachment` model and `datas` binary field***

```
class IrAttachment(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'ir.attachment'

    def process_attachment(self, values):
        pass

    @api.model
    def create(self, values):
        self.process_attachment(values)
        return super(IrAttachment, self).create(values)

    @api.multi
    def write(self, values):
        self.process_attachment(values)
        return super(IrAttachment, self).write(values)
```

Comment: It works, but whatever I have changed in my overridden function, has no effect on the file that is loaded in addons/web/controllers/main.py:upload_attachment(), I have edited the question

Comment: If I understand, the problem is that the values saved in the database are converted but the attachments shown in the WebClient did not change (it still swho the files you uploded)?

Comment: It doesn't show the files in the web client, because there is an error somewhere. In main.py the file has it's old name, but I have changed it in my module. I guess this is why the error occurs.

Comment: Please edit your question and add  the last error log lines.

Comment: Added EDIT 2 to the question

Comment: The log error tells you that you provided a tuple instead of binary data, check the value of `datas` if there is a trailing comma.

Comment: Yes, there was a trailing coma that I didn't notice until now. Like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/20999708/6505678

Answer (score 2):

It seems that overwriting model's `write`/`create` functions is way to go. But for the reference here is how its done for Image field.

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/edacc0fc920e27b9759408887762fcba284ee391/odoo/fields.py#L2079

Comment: Thank you, your answer is very useful too, and too bad I can't accept two answers as correct, as they both helped.